# Что означают два аргумента в вызове $('img.nivoLarge', link)?

Tags: jquery

Продолжаю разбирать плагин, объясните смысл строки

```
var imgLarge = $('img.nivoLarge', link); // ?
```

Не понимаю, что это означает. Файрбагом выяснил, что imgLarge - это с классом .nivolarge
Что означают 2 аргумента в `$();`?

Исходник плагина: http://jsfiddle.net/Ua4b6/

Comment: @olegall, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

> ЧТо означают 2 аргумента в $();

контекст, эквивалентно:

```
$(link).find('img.nivoLarge')
```

- [Selector Context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context)
- [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)